# BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event in WPF

Tags: backgroundworker

There is a scenario in which a user terminates the application, while it is still processing data via BackgroundWorker. 
I would like to send cancel or terminate command to this method. I tried calling CancelAsync() method, but it obviously didn't work the way I expected and the worker still continued processing.
What is a good way to signal the BackgroundWorker, and especially its RunWorkerCompleted method to stop processing?
Do I have to use state variables?

Comment: Have you set `backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;` ? The only way I know to cancel a backgroundworker is via CancelAsync and with the WorkerSupportsCancellation property and testing the CancellationPending property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code executed when you call CancelAsync() on a BackgroundWorker

```
public void CancelAsync()
{
    if (!this.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString
                 ("BackgroundWorker_WorkerDoesntSupportCancellation"));
    }
    this.cancellationPending = true;
}
```

As you can see, they set the internal `cancellationPending` variable to true after checking the value of `WorkerSupportsCancellation`.

So you need to set `WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;`, when you exit from your app call `backGroundWorkerInstance.CancelAsync()` and inside the DoWork or RunWorkerCompleted test the CancellationPending. If it's true stop your process.