# Background Worker thread not ending on cancellation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, backgroundworker

I am having a little issue, I finally figured out how to add a background worker to my application now my only problem is it does not end the thread, or atleast not fast enough when I am clicking my cancel button. I must be doing something wrong. I would like for it to abort the thread as soon as the button is clicked. Is this feasable? My thread is by no means extensive.

I am going to post some examples of the way I am doing it.

```
    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
    ' AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
End Sub
```

My DoWork Event

```
    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        WorkEventRunning = False

    Else

        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        'my long winded event
         ' more of my long winded event.

   End if
```

My Cancel button Code

```
    Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    'Stop
    If bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
        WorkEventRunning = False
        bw.CancelAsync()
        bw.Dispose()

    End If
```

And my WorkCompleted

```
     Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        'canceled
        WorkEventRunning = False
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    Else
        'done
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: bw.CancellationPending will never be true at the start of DoWork.  It only turns on *later*, when you're running the "long winded" code.  Note that setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to False is a really, Really, REALLY bad idea.  Delete that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DoWork event, test for CancellationPending inside the `long  winded event`.
Supposing that this long procedure contains a For-Loop or a ForEach then at every loop test for CancellationPending

For example:

```
Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
Dim x as Integer
For x = 0 to 1000000
    If worker.CancellationPending = True Then 
        e.Cancel = True 
        Return 
    Else 
       .... ' Execute the works for this loop
    End If
Next
```

The same test could be done inside the RunWorkerCompleted event because CancelAsync() sets the internal value for the CancellationPending property. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222436/backgroundworker-runworkercompleted-event-in-wpf/12222570#12222570) to look at the inner workings of CancelAsync()